# Desenvolvimento Android

Tags: java, android, software

Quais as desvantagens em utilizar o Eclipse ao invés do Android Studio no desenvolvimento de uma aplicação Android?

Quero começar a desenvolver meu Aplicativo, mas por conta de possuir um Hardware bastante limitado acho que vou utilizar a IDE Eclipse mesmo. Preciso saber das desvantagens.

Comment: Obrigado! ... Só não entendi pq deram deslike na minha pergunta, sou iniciante, oras :/

Answer (score 1):

Teoricamente, vc pode desenvolver para android usando o notepad apenas.

O Eclipse é um dos IDEs mais usados para JAVA e até surgir o AS era um dos mais usados também para Android.

Se você não tem opção, use o Eclipse, mas não se compara. Eclipse usa um plugin para se adaptar ao Android. AS é uma versão do IntelliJ feita para Android.

Não é só a edição, testes e debug, mas a compilação, assinatura digital, o versionamento dos aplicativos, e mesmo a atualização do ambiente de trabalho é facilitada e feita toda dentro do Android Studio.